# Error while running stored Proc sp_BlitzIndex (TM) v4.2 - September 03, 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-blitzindex

I am getting below error while running "sp_BlitzIndex(TM) v4.2 - September 03, 2016". My SQL server version is:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)   May 14 2014 18:34:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

The error message is:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzIndex, Line 1373 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   ABCD database failed to process. The user does not have permission to perform this action.
>
> Create temp tables.
>
> ABCD
>   Inserting data into #IndexColumns for clustered indexes and heaps
>   Inserting data into #IndexColumns for nonclustered indexes
>   Inserting data into #IndexSanity
>   Failure populating temp tables.
>   Last @dsql:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
            SELECT    12 AS database_id, 
                    so.object_id, 
                    si.index_id, 
                    si.type,
                    'ABCD' AS database_name, 
                    COALESCE(sc.NAME, 'Unknown') AS [schema_name],
                    COALESCE(so.name, 'Unknown') AS [object_name], 
                    COALESCE(si.name, 'Unknown') AS [index_name],
                    CASE    WHEN so.[type] = CAST('V' AS CHAR(2)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
                    si.is_unique, 
                    si.is_primary_key, 
                    CASE when si.type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_XML,
                    CASE when si.type = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_spatial,
                    CASE when si.type = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_NC_columnstore,
                    CASE when si.type = 5 then 1 else 0 end as is_CX_columnstore,
                    si.is_disabled,
                    si.is_hypothetical, 
                    si.is_padded, 
                    si.fill_factor,
                    CASE WHEN si.filter_definition IS NOT NULL THEN si.filter_definition
                         ELSE ''
                    END AS filter_definition
                    , ISNULL(us.user_seeks, 0), ISNULL(us.user_scans, 0),
                    ISNULL(us.user_lookups, 0), ISNULL(us.user_updates, 0), us.last_user_seek, us.last_user_scan,
                    us.last_user_lookup, us.last_user_update,
                    so.create_date, so.modify_date
            FROM    [ABCD].sys.indexes AS si WITH (NOLOCK)
                    JOIN [ABCD].sys.objects AS so WITH (NOLOCK) ON si.object_id = so.object_id
                                           AND so.is_ms_shipped = 0 /*Exclude objects shipped by Microsoft*/
                                           A...
```

I have db_owner privileges on the database. Not sure what all permission I need to run the same.

Comment: I posted an answer for sp_Blitz but then realized you are asking about sp_BlitzIndex, so I deleted the answer. Looking into sp_BlitzIndex now.

Comment: Are there any databases on the server that you can run it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need VIEW SERVER STATE permission in order to run sp_BlitzIndex. This is because it is querying DMVs.